# Python TCP Socket сервер с беспрерывным алгоритмом

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, tcp

Задание следующее: необходимо сделать сервер, имитирующий систему управления уровнем воды в баке. На нем постоянно осуществляются вычисления матмодели, а также осуществляется отправка значений некоторых переменных клиенту, подключённому к серверу. Использовал модуль socket. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать такой сервер? Не получается сделать сервер, беспрерывно вычисляющий матмодель. Очень круто, если есть примеры решения подобных задач.

Comment: я выделял такие штуки в отдельный процесс через multiprocessing. а ответы пользователю давать по сигналу или по запросу.

Answer (score 3):

"*Не получается сделать сервер, беспрерывно вычисляющий матмодель*".  ---  Сервер, непрерывно производящие вычисления - это по сути программа с бесконечным циклом, на каждом шаге которого выполняется очередной расчет модели. Возможно - с передачей результатов во вне - и не важно куда, то ли в сеть, то-ли в файл, то-ли на монитор оператора.  Надеюсь, создать бесконечный цикл для вас труда не составляет.